# Jquery append and a javascript links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating links from json files on the client side.

```
loadSubjects = function() {
  return importData("themen", function() {
    var i, _i, _ref, _results;
    _results = [];
    for (i = _i = 0, _ref = data.themen.themen.length - 1; 0 <= _ref ? _i <= _ref : _i >= _ref; i = 0 <= _ref ? ++_i : --_i) {
      $("#subjectBtns").append('<a href="javascript:generateSubjectOverview("' + data["themen"]["themen"][i]["dateiName"] + '");" class="btn btn-mghg">' + data["themen"]["themen"][i]["name"] + '</a>');
      console.log('appending: ' + '<a href="javascript:generateSubjectOverview("' + data["themen"]["themen"][i]["dateiName"] + '");" class="btn btn-mghg">' + data["themen"]["themen"][i]["name"] + '</a>');
      _results.push(false);
    }
    return _results;
  });
};
```

I also tired onlick instead of href, but that also didnt work. I am getting the error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

The javascript code looks somewhat messy, but that is, because it´s generated by coffeescript.

the function `importData` is just a short hand for $.getJSON with the path and the callback

Comment: You can't return results from an AJAX callback. The callback function runs asynchronously when the server responds.

Comment: @Barmar: I think the `return` there is to return the `jqXHR` object (or possibly another promise of some kind). Ben is passing in a callback. (Hmmmm... But then, why `return _results;` at the end of the callback? Maybe `importData` does something with that.)

Comment: he said `importData` is just shorthand for `$.getJSON`. Unless it's wrapping the callback in another function that does something with the return value, it won't be used.

Comment: @Barmar: Sometimes people say "shorthand" even when doing a small thing differently. Ben's the only one who can really answer, but is clearly aware of the need for callbacks.

Comment: `return _results;` is just because i am writing in coffeesctipt. it always return the last thing in a codeblock

Comment: and  `importData(filename, callback)` is just `path = 'data/'+filename+'.json'`
and than it just inserts that into $.getJSON so didn´t change a thing to that except it just add the .json suffix and the folder name i wich all my data is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a function when the link is clicked, use the `click` event rather than trying to generate JavaScript source with the arguments in it to put on the `href`:

```
$("#subjectBtns").append(
    $('<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-mghg"></a>')
        .click(generateSubjectOverview.bind(null, data["themen"]["themen"][i]["dateiName"]))
        .append(data["themen"]["themen"][i]["name"])
);
```

This bit:

```
generateSubjectOverview.bind(null, data["themen"]["themen"][i]["dateiName"])
```

...looks up the value from the `data` object and binds that value to `generateSubjectOverview`, setting up a `click` handler to call the resulting bound function. The result is the same, but you don't make an unnecessary round-trip through JavaScript source code, so this works not just for strings and numbers, but any kind of argument you may want to pass.

---

Note: `Function#bind` is an ES5 feature. If you still need to support really old browsers (IE8, for instance), it can be shimmed. Search for "Function bind shim" to find options.

Comment: what does the `null` in `.click(generateSubjectOverview.bind(null, data["themen"]["themen"][i]["dateiName"]))` do?

Comment: @Ben: The first argument to `Function#bind` determines what `this` will be when the original function is called: In loose mode, if it's `undefined` or `null`, the original function is called with `this` equal to the global object (`window`, on browsers). (In strict mode, the value is used as-is.) Any other arguments you give `bind` are passed on to the called function. So in loose mode, if you do `var bound = foo.bind(null, 1, 2);` and then you do `bound('a', 'b', 'c');`, `foo` gets called with `this` being the global object and the arguments `1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c'`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with `'` and `"`. change this

```
 $("#subjectBtns").append('<a href="javascript:generateSubjectOverview("' + data["themen"]["themen"][i]["dateiName"] + '");" class="btn btn-mghg">' + data["themen"]["themen"][i]["name"] + '</a>');
```

to this

```
 $("#subjectBtns").append('<a href="javascript:generateSubjectOverview(\"' + data["themen"]["themen"][i]["dateiName"] + '\");" class="btn btn-mghg">' + data["themen"]["themen"][i]["name"] + '</a>');
```

Comment: what do those slashes do?

Comment: the slashes allow to show the char `"` inside a string which is between `" String "`